# transition not working in AppBarLayout android

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout, android-transitions

I have RecyclerView with the following layout for items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_name_details">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        style="@style/input_text_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When clicked on an item an activity is shown with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="80dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_name_details">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    style="@style/input_text_style"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>...
```

Unfortunately the value of the `TextInputEditText` is not showing when the second activity is displayed. But when I click on the `TextInputEditText` the value is then displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first layout to this one solved the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/name_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:transitionName="@string/transition_name_details">


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    style="@style/input_text_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```